# How does one see all defined routes within Kohana?

Tags: routes, kohana

What I mean to say is, is there a way to print out what routes Kohana has set?  I know what I'm trying to set, and I'm doing it programmatically, but since it's not finding the route, I'd like to just see what Kohana has defined.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read an official documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$routes = Route::all();`

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Route#all

Comment: Thank you.  Somehow I missed that!